# Passing reference to XBMC json-rpc to identify answer later

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, json-rpc, xbmc

I am using XBMC json-rpc with websockets. When I send json request like `"method":"Playlist.OnClear"` I get response `{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"OK"}`.

So if I'll send multiple requests I will get multiple responses and I won't be able to identify which response refers to which request. Is it possible to pass some additional data to request so that it would be added to response (like `context` in jquery ajax call)?

I don't know is it related to XBMC or json-rpc in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this question was not answered because it is slightly inaccurate.

Firstly there is no method "Playlist.OnClear,  rather Playlist.OnClear is only a non-solicited notification from the media player, on that states the playlist was cleared.
Now the playlist might clear directly as a result of another request you had made, for example Playlist.Clear comes to mind, which is indeed a method.

So when you send the valid json packet

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Playlist.Clear","params":{"playlistid":0},"id":10101}
```

You can use the "id" key to add a, guess what, an id to the request, and that very same id will be returned from the mediaplayer

```
{"id":10101,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"OK"}
```

Furthermore, it is possible to write paired web based requests/response code, but that's not even necessary considering the above...

Comment: you rock! ID is the key I was looking for such a long time :) And yes, it was my mistake on `Playlist.OnClear` method name.